# Error while setting up a remote ssh host on a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to setup a remote ssh host on a docker container to perform jenkins jobs from another container. MY Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM Centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server && \
    yum install -y passwd

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo remote_user:1234 | chpasswd  && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized-keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized-keys

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen -A
EXPOSE 22
RUN r -rf /run/nologin

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

I run into this following error:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen -A' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Can you please help me correct this issue?

Comment: try creating your keys (public and private) on local and then copying them both.

Comment: Jenkins can [directly run Docker containers](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).  You don't need to try to set up an ssh daemon, with its attendant security problems.

Comment: Hi @Opri, I tried doing that and ended up with the same error.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I'm trying to run jenkins on a remote ssh host in particular and hence this requirement. It's a part of my coursework.